# Gitlab Registry : Access Denied

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to push a simple docker image on my docker registry and I get an access denied after a successful `docker login`.

I created a Personnal Access Token with `api` scope.

1)  I log in with :

`docker login -u gitlab-repository -p <token> registry.gitlab.com`

I got *Login Succeeded*.

2) Then :  `docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/<username>/test-ci .`

3) And finaly when I push :
 `docker push registry.gitlab.com/<username>/test-ci`

I get this error : **unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied**

Comment: what kind of runner are you using? Because that can change the requirements/setup. You also have `-u gitlab-repository` but is `gitlab-repository` your username? As per the docs, if you're using a PAT, it should be your username: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#authenticating-to-the-container-registry

Comment: For now I'm using a gitlab shared runner. 
Thanks it works, I was indeed using my Personal Access Token with the name of my PAT as username

Comment: Glad it worked. I've posted my comment as an answer as well so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message suggests an authentication error. Most likely it's:

`-u gitlab-repository`

The option `-u` expects your username [as per the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#authenticating-to-the-container-registry).